How to make tables of information for variables
I'm learning Python and making a Dungeons & Dragons-based text-based game.  I'm curious if there's a way to make a table or something so I don't have to specify the same variables (enemy_ac, enemy_hp, etc.) every time for each creature.
#Function to spawn an enemy
def encounter():
    global enemy
    global enemy_weapon
    global enemy_ac
    global enemy_hp
    global enemy_attack_mod
    global enemy_damage_mod
    global enemy_exp

    #print("Debug: Running Encounter Function")
    chance_encounter = randint(1,100)
    if chance_encounter in range(90,96):
        enemy = "Orc"
        enemy_weapon = "Greataxe"
        enemy_ac = 13
        enemy_hp = 15
        enemy_attack_mod = 5
        enemy_damage_mod = 3
        enemy_exp = 100
        print("An Orc howls in bloodlust as it brings its Greataxe to bare!!")
        print("")
    elif chance_encounter >= 97:
        enemy = "Worg"
        enemy_weapon = "Bite"
        enemy_ac = 13
        enemy_hp = 26
        enemy_attack_mod = 5
        enemy_damage_mod = 3
        enemy_exp = 100
        print(r"""
                          ,
               ,,/( ,,,,,,,,,,___,,
              )b     ,,,           "`,_,
             /(     /                   `,
            L/7_/\,,|            /        \
             ,`      `,  \     ,|          \
              ,      /  /``````||      |\,  \__,)))
                    /  / |      \\     \  \,,,,,,/
                   |  /  |       \\   )/
                   \ (|  )     ,,//   /
                    `_)_/     ((___/"'
            """)
        print("A Worg is released into the arena!!")
        print("")
    else:
        enemy = "Goblin"
        enemy_weapon = "Scimitar"
        enemy_ac = 15
        enemy_hp = 7
        enemy_attack_mod = 4
        enemy_damage_mod = 2
        enemy_exp = 50
        print(r"""
              /(.-""-.)\      
          |\  \/      \/  /|  
          | \ / =.  .= \ / |  
          \( \   o\/o   / )/  
           \_, '-/  \-' ,_/   
             /   \__/   \     
             \ \__/\__/ /     
           ___\ \|--|/ /___   
         /`    \      /    `\  
        /       '----'       \
        """)
        print ("A frenzied Goblin charges you with a Scimitar!!")

Any advice appreciated - thanks!
Not sure how to even start approaching this... Googling around.

There's a million and one ways to do this, but as a beginner, I'd recommend you look at either YAML or JSON files that can easily be externally edited and made available to your program with just a line or two of code.

Thanks @KenY-N.  I am somewhat (using the term VERY loosely) familiar with YAML and JSON but wasn't sure how to call the external file and how to convert it into something the Python script can understand.  I'll try to research that.

The idea of having "the same variables" for different "instances" of objects, like enemies, or rooms, in a game, is the idea of "object orientation".
In Python we usually will create a custom object type using the class statement - a class "Enemy" could hold the name, weapon, hp, attack_mod attributes as you requires. ("Attribute" is the name of a variable when attached to an object).
Try reading the Python tutorial lessons on "class" and check if you can use them. To minimize boiler plate in this code you might want to use "dataclasses". https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Thanks @jsbueno - I ended up going the YAML file route and think this is resolved.

Going the YAML route seemed to work well!
My YAML file:
---
enemies:
  Goblin:
    weapon: Scimitar
    ac: 15
    hp: 7
    attack_mod: 4
    damage_mod: 2
    exp: 50

  Orc:
    weapon: Greataxe
    ac: 13
    hp: 15
    attack_mod: 5
    damage_mod: 3
    exp: 100

  Worg:
    weapon: Bite
    ac: 13
    hp: 26
    attack_mod: 5
    damage_mod: 3
    exp: 100

My updated code:
#Function to spawn an enemy
def encounter():

    with open('variables.yaml', 'r') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    #print(doc["enemies"]["Goblin"]["weapon"])

    global enemy
    global enemy_weapon
    global enemy_ac
    global enemy_hp
    global enemy_attack_mod
    global enemy_damage_mod
    global enemy_exp

    chance_encounter = randint(1,100)
    if chance_encounter in range(90,96):
        enemy = "Orc"
        print("An Orc howls in bloodlust as it brings its Greataxe to bare!!")
        print("")
    elif chance_encounter >= 97:
        enemy = "Worg"
        print(r"""
                          ,
               ,,/( ,,,,,,,,,,___,,
              )b     ,,,           "`,_,
             /(     /                   `,
            L/7_/\,,|            /        \
             ,`      `,  \     ,|          \
              ,      /  /``````||      |\,  \__,)))
                    /  / |      \\     \  \,,,,,,/
                   |  /  |       \\   )/
                   \ (|  )     ,,//   /
                    `_)_/     ((___/"'
            """)
        print("A Worg is released into the arena!!")
        print("")
    else:
        enemy = "Goblin"
        print(r"""
              /(.-""-.)\      
          |\  \/      \/  /|  
          | \ / =.  .= \ / |  
          \( \   o\/o   / )/  
           \_, '-/  \-' ,_/   
             /   \__/   \     
             \ \__/\__/ /     
           ___\ \|--|/ /___   
         /`    \      /    `\  
        /       '----'       \
        """)
        print ("A frenzied Goblin charges you with a Scimitar!!")
    
    enemy_weapon = doc["enemies"][(enemy)]["weapon"]
    enemy_ac = doc["enemies"][(enemy)]["ac"]
    enemy_hp = doc["enemies"][(enemy)]["hp"]
    enemy_attack_mod = doc["enemies"][(enemy)]["attack_mod"]
    enemy_damage_mod = doc["enemies"][(enemy)]["damage_mod"]
    enemy_exp = doc["enemies"][(enemy)]["exp"]

I think this will work nicely to plug all my variables (I have stuff for equipment, etc.)!  Thanks!
